# How to make a reusable AngularJs components

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

This seems like it should be easy, but I can't find documentation on it.  I'm wondering how to make an Angular component (let's say a filter) reusable in different apps.  I've made a simple filter that formats a phone number, and I'd like to be able to use it in any app.  Currently it is declared like this:

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', ['ngSanitize']);

myModule.filter('formatFilter', function() {
  return function(input) {
    return input.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "($1) $2-$3");
  }
});
```

The question is how to make this filter reusable.  Right now it's just attached to 'myModule', but how can I take it out of this file so I can reuse it elsewhere too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You started OK by encapsulating your filter in a separate module. For other apps to use it, those apps will just need to include source code of your filter and declare dependency on a module:

`angular.module('myApp',['myModule'])`

You would probably like to rename your filter-holding module to something more meaningful, something like `phoneFormatter` or sth.

Comment: Alright, so let's say I have a .js file called myModule.js.  I just add that to my page, initialize my new module like you mentioned, call {{phoneNumber|formatFilter}} and that's it?  p.s. the actual filter formats more that just phone numbers, hence the more abstract name.  I just simplified it when asking the question.

Answer (score 2):

Just as an example :

This is a reusable filter declared as a module, so only needs to be injected on the app:

Filter:

```
angular.module("lov-filter", []).filter('StartOnPage', function () {
    return function (input, start) {
        start = +start;
        return input.slice(start);
    }
});
```

App:

> var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['lov-filter'])
>       .config(function () {
>
> ```
> });
> ```

Used on this angular directive: https://github.com/rolandocc/lov-angular-directive